# How to make a svg not overflowing its parent container height with flex-box

Tags: html, css, svg, tailwind-css

I'm trying to drop an SVG into a layout with flex sizing, but I'm unable to make it take the full height of its parent and keep the ratio on width.

```html
<div class="relative container h-80 mx-auto bg-green-200 p-5 flex">
  <div class="absolute top-0 font-semibold">Container border</div>
  <div class="flex-1 bg-red-200">
     <svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" />
          </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-blue-200 font-bold">Right part</div>
  <div/>
```

As a result, the rectangle is overflowing

[Here is a sandbox using Tailwind CSS](https://play.tailwindcss.com/dn8NYTNIQW) with minimum repro, I've tried a lot of properties but I'm unable to achieve my use case

Could anyone help me with that one?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving your SVG `h-full w-full` will prevent the overflow. The SVG has a different aspect ratio than your container so if you want it to "fit" the container then you'll also want to add the attribute `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to your SVG tag, but if you put other graphical content in the SVG it will be distorted.

Here's an example on Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/O799SO8UfD